# Difference between a Packaged App and a Legacy Packaged App in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Basically packaged apps do not appear on the Chrome App Store, but legacy packaged apps do. The [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html) states that

> Warning: All content in this doc refers to the legacy version of packaged apps. Your legacy packaged apps will still work, but you won't have access to any of the new APIs. Check out the new version of packaged apps; otherwise, you're **missing out**!

The question is, what will you be missing out when using a *legacy packaged app* instead of a *packaged app* ? (apart from not appearing in the Chrome App Store)

Comment: Packaged apps don't appear in Chrome Web Store search because they are in developer preview, but they certainly will. For now, you can distribute the direct CWS URL of your packaged app to your trusted testers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better window geometry control (open outside of the browser), security, access to more powerful APIs, etc.

See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, would you also say that generally packaged apps should have less problems working on different CPU architectures then apps developed with native code ?

Comment: Packaged apps are isolated from platform specifics to a similar level as web pages. If you're using simply HTML/CSS/JS you can ignore the CPU architecture. Screen size and input modality (mouse, touchpad, touchscreen) would still benefit from your app planning for them.